# Parse JSON with similar elements using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have this type of JSON (just a short sample):

```
"orderProducts": [
        {
            "id": 135,
            "order_id": 39,
            "product_id": 49,
            "product_code": "",
            "size_id": 13,
            "quantity": 2,
            "product": {
                "id": 49,
                "code": "",
                "factory_id": 2,
                "product_category_id": 1,
                "sex_id": null,
                "season_id": null,
                "product_type_id": null,
                "type_id": null,
                "color_id": null,
                "year_id": null,
                "image_1": "bceef8b28ae2a1797ca0c6300021100d.jpeg",
                "image_2": "",
                "image_3": "",
                "notes": "",
                "status": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 136,
            "order_id": 39,
            "product_id": 49,
            "product_code": "",
            "size_id": 14,
            "quantity": 3,
            "product": {
                "id": 49,
                "code": "",
                "factory_id": 2,
                "product_category_id": 1,
                "sex_id": null,
                "season_id": null,
                "product_type_id": null,
                "type_id": null,
                "color_id": null,
                "year_id": null,
                "image_1": "bceef8b28ae2a1797ca0c6300021100d.jpeg",
                "image_2": "",
                "image_3": "",
                "notes": "",
                "status": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 137,
            "order_id": 39,
            "product_id": 48,
            "product_code": "",
            "size_id": null,
            "quantity": 24,
            "product": {
                "id": 48,
                "code": "",
                "factory_id": 2,
                "product_category_id": null,
                "sex_id": null,
                "season_id": null,
                "product_type_id": null,
                "type_id": null,
                "color_id": null,
                "year_id": null,
                "image_1": "2aee8660b4218bf549c2d9345beb2a01.jpeg",
                "image_2": "",
                "image_3": "",
                "notes": "",
                "status": 10
            }
        }]
```

Items I need to parse are: `product_id`, `size_id` and `quantity`. For this, I have created this struct:

```
struct Products {
    let id: String
    let quantities: [(sizeId: String, quantity: String)]?

    init(id: String, quantities: [(sizeId: String, quantity: String)]) {
        self.id = id
        self.quantities = quantities
    }
}
```

The end result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
[Products(id: "49", quantities: [(sizeId: "13", quantity: "2"), (sizeId: "14", quantity: "3")]), 
Products(id: "48", quantities: [(sizeId: "null", quantity: "24")])]
```

When parsing using SwiftyJSON, I do this:

```
for productId in products.arrayValue {
                        self.productWithQuantites.append(Products(id: productId["product_id"].stringValue,
                                                                  quantities: [(sizeId: productId["size_id"].stringValue,
                                                                                quantity: productId["quantity"].stringValue)]))

                    }
```

But I get this:

```
    [Products(id: "49", quantities: [(sizeId: "13", quantity: "2")]),
Products(id: "49", quantities: [(sizeId: "14", quantity: "3")],
Products(id: "48", quantities: [(sizeId: "null", quantity: "24")])]
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I append new quantities to my existing elements? Would be thankful for a code sample or any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier modification in loops like this, you should make `Products` a class, since it's passed by reference. Also, make `quantities` to a `var` in your `Products` and replace the parsing code to this:

```
for product in products.arrayValue {
    let productId = product["product_id"].stringValue

    let quantity = (sizeId: product["size_id"].stringValue,
                    quantity: product["quantity"].stringValue)

    if let product = self.productWithQuantites.filter({ $0.id == productId }).first {
        product.quantities?.append(quantity)
    } else {
        self.productWithQuantites.append(Products(id: productId, quantities: [quantity]))
    }
}
```

This code appends a new tuple to the `quantities` property of an existing product, or if it does not exist, it creates a new `Products` and appends that to `productWithQuantites`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but I'm getting error here: `product.quantities.append(quantity)` - `Value of type '[(sizeId: String, quantity: String)]?' has no member 'append'`

Comment: @TarasTomchuk Sorry, I missed a question mark there. It should be `product.quantities?.append(quantity)`, since `quantities` is an optional.

Comment: @ Tamás Sengel Also, `if let product` should be changed to `if var product`, as it throws error with product being let. But, the output I get here is:  `[Products(id: "49", quantities: Optional([(sizeId: "13", quantity: "2")])), Products(id: "48", quantities: Optional([(sizeId: "", quantity: "24")]))]` So, it doesn't seem to add other quantities

Comment: Oops, my bad; I did not realize that `Products` is a **struct** and not a class. Since classes are passed by reference, it's much easier to modify them in a loop like this. I'd suggest making `Products` a class.

Comment: Changed to a class, now my output looks like this - `[Products, Products]`

Comment: @TarasTomchuk Try using `dump` instead of `print`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181966/discussion-between-tamas-sengel-and-taras-tomchuk).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 `SwiftyJSON` became obsolete in favor of the `Codable` protocol.

Don't use tuples in structs, separate the values and group the `Product` (singular form is preferable) instances into a dictionary depending on the product id.

Assuming `data` contains the JSON raw data create these tiny structs

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let orderProducts : [Product]
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let productId : Int
    let sizeId : Int?
}
```

Decode the JSON into the structs and group the array with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`

```
do {
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
   let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
   let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: result.orderProducts, by: {$0.productId})
   print(groupedDictionary)
   // [49: [Product(id: 135, productId: 49, sizeId: Optional(13)), 
   //      Product(id: 136, productId: 49, sizeId: Optional(14))], 
   //  48: [Product(id: 137, productId: 48, sizeId: nil)]]

} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but project I have is using SwiftyJSON everywhere, so I must stick to it

Comment: I highly recommend to *upgrade* to `Codable`. It's much more efficient.

Comment: I will, in my next project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to receive like that, since in your JSON there are two entries, with `"product_id": 49`

So you can solve it as, after parsing your json, by having two for loops to remove once you find the same item more than once as following:

```
for i in 0..<productWithQuantites.count {
        for j in 0..<productWithQuantites.count {
            if productWithQuantites[i].productID == productWithQuantites[j].productID {
                productWithQuantites.remove(at: j)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Alamofire with JSONDecoder instead swiftyjson  and more reference you can watch this video which is available on this link https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss